# Java Die, Counting Snake Eyes

Tags: java, jpl

Okay so for university, we have to Create  two Die objects and roll them several times, counting the number of snake eyes that occur.

this is the code I have, I need some help as every time I compile and execute my program, I get a fail on it. I'm not 100% sure where i'm going wrong, and I Don't know entirely whether solutions will help unless you went to my university, but any help is appreciated :) Thanks.

The Fail is - http://i.imgur.com/ghcOlpP.png

(This is all coded in JPLIDE)

```
final int ROLLS = 500;
  int num1, num2, count = 0;

  Die die1 = new Die();
  Die die2 = new Die();

  for (int roll=1; roll <= ROLLS; roll++)
  {num1 = 1;
    num2 = 1;

    if (num1 == 1 && num2 == 1)    // check for snake eyes
      count++;
  }

  System.out.println ("Number of rolls: " + ROLLS);
  System.out.println ("Number of snake eyes: " + count);
  System.out.println ("Ratio: " + (float)count / ROLLS);
}}}

class Die
{private final int MAX = 6;  // maximum face value
  private int faceValue;  // current value showing on the die

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Constructor: Sets the initial face value of this die.
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public Die()
  {faceValue = 1;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Computes a new face value for this die and returns the result.
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public int roll()
  {faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;
    return faceValue;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Face value mutator. The face value is not modified if the
  //  specified value is not valid.
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public void setFaceValue (int value)
  {if (value > 0 && value <= MAX)
    faceValue = value;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Face value accessor.
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public int getFaceValue()
  {return faceValue;
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Returns a string representation of this die.
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public String toString()
  {String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "get a fail" mean. If you have an error, post it. Errors are meaningful pieces of data.

Comment: This is what it looks like when getting a fail http://i.imgur.com/ghcOlpP.png

Comment: The `input -> expected output` criteria is empty in your test chart?

Comment: Thats true, didn't occur to me. I might have to ask my lecturer for some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int roll=1; roll <= ROLLS; roll++) {
num1 = 1;
num2 = 1;

if (num1 == 1 && num2 == 1)    // check for snake eyes
  count++;
}
```

This looks wrong. You set `num1 = 1` and `num2 = 1` and then check if both are equal to 1.. of course they are going to be equal to 1. I assume you meant to do something like

`num1 = die1.roll()`
`num2 = die2.roll()`

This will at least make it so that you don't have snake eyes all 500 times.

Comment: Popped that in, and still got a fail but I think its cause the input -> expected output is empty. http://i.imgur.com/7S9Cjy2.png  But its not 500 Snake eyes anymore

Comment: You're going to have to see what the input and expected output is to know more about what your code is actually supposed to do. @Tyxex